# Any solution to system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I need ANY combination of 8 variables which satisfy:

```
a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h=0
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2+g^2+h^2=1
a*b+b*c+c*d+d*e+e*f+f*g+g*h+a*h>2/3
```

Ideally these would be numbers having simple closed forms...

If I exchange third restriction with

```
a*b+b*c+c*d+d*e+e*f+f*g+g*h+a*h=2/3
```

I get a solution a=b=c=6^(-0.5); e=f=g=-6^(-0.5); d=h=0;

Comment: Ok, then please show us what you have tried.

Comment: @rm-rf I have tried entering those three restrictions into "Free-form input". Before that I figured an answer to a modified version analytically. Actually this question looks so straightforward to me that if I knew how to proceed the thread wouldn't even exist...

Comment: $\left(\sqrt{1/8}, 1/2,\sqrt{1/8}, 0, -\sqrt{1/8}, -1/2, -\sqrt{1/8}, 0\right)$ works: the third expression evaluates to $\sqrt{1/2} \gt 2/3$.  (This in fact is the maximum possible value it can attain subject to the restrictions.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a special kind of problem which succumbs to a standard approach.

#### Analysis

The question can be solved by maximizing $x \mathbb{A} x'$ and checking that this maximum exceeds $2/3$.  The restrictions are (1) that $x=(a,b,\ldots,h)$ must have unit square length and (2) be orthogonal to $e_1 = (1,1,\ldots, 1)$, where $A$ is the matrix

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$$

#### Solution

Because $\mathbb{A}$ is obviously a rotation matrix (it represents a cyclic permutation of the eight basis vectors), $e_1$ (by virtue of its constant coefficients) must be an eigenvector.  Seven other *complex* eigenvectors can be found orthogonal to $e_1$.  Their eigenvalues fall into three groups of complex conjugates, representing rotations by primitive multiples of $2\pi/8$, and one real eigenvalue of $-1$, representing a rotation by $\pi$.  We seek the *smallest* rotation among these rotations, because that corresponds to the *largest* cosine of the angle, which geometrically is what $x\mathbb{A} x'$ is computing.

The eigensystem can be obtained and displayed as

```
MatrixForm /@ ({e, ev} = Eigensystem[a = RotateRight[#, 1] & /@ IdentityMatrix[8]] // Simplify)
```

The cosines are the real parts of the eigenvalues `e`:

```
Re[e]
```

> $\left\{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-1,0,0,1\right\}$

The two largest real parts, $1/\sqrt{2}\approx 0.7071 \gt 2/3$, occur in the third and fourth places.  The real parts of either the third or fourth *normalized* eigenvectors therefore afford values of $x$ where the desired maximum is attained:

```
x = Normalize @ (Re /@ ev[[3]])
```

> $\left\{\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}},0,-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{2}\right\}$

If any of this seems too abstract, let's check all the requirements:

1. Confirm $x$ is orthogonal to $e_1$:

   ```
   x .ConstantArray[1, 8]
   ```

   > $0$
2. Confirm $x$ has unit squared length:

   ```
   x . x
   ```

   > $1$
3. Compute $x\mathbb{A} x'$:

   ```
   x . a . x
   ```

   > $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Thanks. And you are actually very good at mathematical aspect of this.

Comment: Yeah, that was a great math answer, but it didn't shed much light on how to solve similar problems with Mathematica.

Comment: It all depends on what you might recognize as being "similar," @Jerry.  At the outset this answer announces the problem is special--it's a little hard to characterize it.  The "standard approach" I describe is a systematic way to solve a system involving an inequality by means of optimizing a function.  As always, YMMV.