# How to find ANY solution to an underdetermined system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I have certain systems of equations for which I need ANY solution if one exists. Can I get MMa to just do that?

This doesn't work:

```
nParticles = 4;
nPow = 2;
m = {0, 1, 0, 1};
soln = Table[Sum[a[i]^n, {i, 1, nParticles}]/nParticles == m[[n]], {n, 1, nPow}];
start = Table[{a[i], RandomReal[1] - .5}, {i, 1, nParticles}];
aa = FindRoot[soln, start]
```

...because it's underdetermined. It works perfectly if nParticles==nPow.

There's a similar question here:
[Any solution to system of equations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21737/any-solution-to-system-of-equations)
but the Answer-er gave an elegant MATH solution instead of a MMa solution.

Comment: Try `FindInstance[soln, {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]}]`.

Comment: For a `FindRoot` type of approach, you can for a sum of squares and use `FindMinimum`. If the min is zero, you have located a root.

Answer (score 4):

I used something like the following in [Plotting implicitly-defined space curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves/64923#64923).

```
Clear[findPoint, pseudonewton];
pseudonewton[f_List, vars_] := pseudonewton[f, D[f, {vars}]]; 
pseudonewton[f_List, df_?MatrixQ, vars_] := 
 With[{df0 = df /. Thread[vars -> #], f0 = f /. Thread[vars -> #]},
   # - PseudoInverse[df0].f0] &;

findPoint[eqs_List, {vars_, p0_}] := 
  With[{f = eqs /. {Equal -> Subtract}}, 
   Thread[vars -> 
     NestWhile[pseudonewton[f, D[f, {vars}], vars], p0, 
      Norm[f /. Thread[vars -> #]] > 1*^-15 &, 2, 100]]
   ];

findPoint[soln, Transpose@start]
(*  {a[1] -> 0.741866, a[2] -> -0.0513263, a[3] -> -1.61188, a[4] -> 0.921336}  *)

soln /. %
(*  {True, True}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not hard.

```
vars = Table[a[i], {i, 1, nParticles}];
FindInstance[soln, vars]

(* {{a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> -Sqrt[2], a[4] -> Sqrt[2]}} *)
```