# How can I solve this equation: $(47^{(u + 1)} + 3^{(u + 1)})/(u + 1) ==50^{1.5}/1.5$?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[(47^(u + 1) + 3^(u + 1))/(u + 1) ==(50^1.5)/1.5,u]
```

The code I tried is above, but it showed me a message problem

> "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the
>   \ system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present
>   \ in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact
>   \ input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may
>   help."

Anyone has any ideas?

I made a Plot too and it worked. So I don't understand why solve failed.

```
Plot[(47^(u + 1) + 3^(u + 1))/(u + 1), {u, -50, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 236}]
```

Comment: Transcendental equations have no closed-form solutions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation. Try `NSolve` a numeric solver.

Comment: Solve can find the exact solution in terms of `Root` objects. Just restrict the domain to real numbers and rewrite $1.5$ as $3/2$. `Solve[(47^(u + 1) + 3^(u + 1))/(u + 1) == (50^(3/2))/(3/2), u, Reals]`

Comment: Why wouldn't you immediately make the substitution $u+1 \to v$ and evaluate the numerical value on the r.h.s. (or call it $C$), to simplify things?

Comment: Thank you all for your help,I'm new to the software but with your help I've been able to  manage!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the comment by @MariuszIwaniuk. But you still can get the numbers.

```
With[
 {
  lhseqn = (47^(u + 1) + 3^(u + 1))/(u + 1),
  rhseqn = (50^1.5)/1.5
  },
 {u, lhseqn} /. Solve@Reduce[
    lhseqn == rhseqn
    , u
    , Reals
    ]
 ]

(* {{-0.99133, 235.702}, {0.524412, 235.702}} *)

Plot[
 {(3^(1 + u) + 47^(1 + u))/(1 + u), 235.70226039551585`}
 , {u, -2, 1}
 , Epilog -> {
   Red,
   PointSize[Large],
   Point[
    {
     {-0.9913301038667653`, 235.702260395515`},
     {0.5244122630164348`, 235.7022603955158`}
     }
    ]
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very specific and it helped!

Answer (score 8):

Solve can solve this equation:

```
Solve[(47^(u+1)+3^(u+1))/(u+1)==(50^(3/2))/(3/2) && Abs[u]<1,u, Reals]

(* {{u->Root[{500 Sqrt[2]-3^(2+#1)-3 47^(1+#1)+500 Sqrt[2] #1&,-0.99133010386676537502}]},{u->Root[{500 Sqrt[2]-3^(2+#1)-3 47^(1+#1)+500 Sqrt[2] #1&,0.52441226301643480967}]}} *)
```

This is an exact solution!

```
N[%]

(* {{u->-0.99133},{u->0.524412}} *)
```

Comment: You don't even need to add `Abs[u]<1`. At least in v.11.3

Comment: @roman465. Good observation, thanks. Sometimes such a restriction is necessary. Compare `Solve[5/4 Sin[x] == ArcTan[x] , x, Reals]`, which Mathematica cannot solve, with `Solve[5/4 Sin[x] == ArcTan[x] && Abs[x] < 10 , x, Reals]`, which returns the three solutions.

Answer (score 8):

I have recently been teaching myself to recast root-finding problems in order to use the `NDSolve` machinery and find multiple roots of a function numerically in one go, so I am taking the opportunity here to give it a go.

First, we recast the equation as a root-finding problem. In other words, instead of looking for $u$ such that `lefthandside == righthandside`, we look for `u` such that `f[u_] := lefthandside - righthandside` crosses zero, if that can be done safely.

We then build a contrived differential equation for which `f[u]` is a solution and we use `NDSolve` to solve it, while monitoring the progress of the integration with `WhenEvent`, looking for zero crossings, which are `Sow`n and collected with `Reap`:

```
Clear[f]
f[u_] := (47^(u + 1) + 3^(u + 1))/(u + 1) - (50^1.5)/1.5

sol =
  Reap@
   NDSolve[{
      D[y[u], u] == D[f[u], u], y[0] == f[0],
      WhenEvent[y[u] == 0, Sow[u]]},
     y, {u, -2, 2}
   ];
```

Note that we have to have an idea of the range wherein we might find the roots, in order to set appropriate integration boundaries, but then again that would be necessary with any other numerical method. Also, `NDSolve` rightfully complains about a discontinuity in this case, but soldiers on. The result contains our root estimates:

```
sol[[2, 1]]
(* Out: {-0.99133, 0.524412} *)
```

Showing that in a plot together with the `f[x]` function:

```
Show[
  Plot[f[u], {u, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> 1000],
  ListPlot[
    Callout[
      {#, 0}, Round[#, 0.001],
      LabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Medium]
    ] & /@ sol[[2, 1]],
    PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.015]}
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The root candidates found with this method can also be further refined using `FindRoot`, using them as initial conditions for the root search.

---

This technique has been mentioned before on the site. See e.g. [Find all roots of an interpolating function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16439/27951), or [How can I find solutions for this equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98926/27951), and I am sure in other posts that I might have missed.