# Solve a system of 4-th order polynomial equations (numerically)

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, numerical-value

I have a function defined on $ S^6 \times S^6 $ (two spheres embedded in $ \mathbb{R}^7 $ individually). Let us call this vector $ \vec{f}(\vec{x},\vec{y}) $, where $ \vec{x} $ and $ \vec{y} $ are points in the two spheres. The target space of the function if $ \mathbb{R}^{13} $, namely $ \vec{f}: S^6 \times S^6 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{13} $. The vectors $ \vec{x}, \vec{y} $ live in the spheres, so $ \vec{x} \cdot \vec{x} = 1 $ and $ \vec{y} \cdot \vec{y} = 1 $.

**This is the problem I am trying to solve.** I want to find *at least* two points $ {\vec{x}_0,\vec{y}_0} $ such that

$$
\vec{f}(\vec{x}_0, \vec{y}_0) = \vec{0}
$$

Each entry $ \vec{f} $ is a polynomial of the 4-th order in the entries of the vectors and can be written formally as

$$
f^i(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \sum_{jknm} a^{i}_{jknm} x^j x^k y^n y^m
$$
where $ a^{i}_{jknm} $s are real coefficients.

I have saved the vector $ \vec{f} $ in [this file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=60179660196594732740) `.wbx` (download it) that you can import with the command

```
Uncompress @ Import["vector.wbx", "String"]
```

In this file, the entries of the vectors $ \vec{x} $ and $ \vec{y} $ are labelled with $ x_i $ and $ y_i $ for $ i = 1, 2, ..., 7 $.

Given the explicit values of the coefficients $ a^i_{jknm} $, I have tried to solve the system with *Mathematica*. Obviously, the system is very difficult and an analytic solution is hard to find. So, I have tried to find the solution numerically, but *Mathematica* takes too long and does not give an answer.

I have tried with

```
Solve[{f == Table[0, {i, 1, 13}, x.x == 1, y.y == 1}, {x, y} // Flatten]
NSolve[{f == Table[0, {i, 1, 13}, x.x == 1, y.y == 1}, {x , y} // Flatten]
```

and also I have looked if *Mathematica* can find just a solution with

```
FindInstance[{f == Table[0, {i, 1, 13}, x.x == 1, y.y == 1}, {x, y} // Flatten]
```

but still it takes too long.

Do you have any suggestion in order to solve this problem with *Mathematica*?

Comment: What about `FindRoot`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thanks for the suggestion. The point is that I have 13 equations from the system + the 2 constraints $\vec{x}.\vec{x}=1$,  $\vec{y}.\vec{y}=1$ which gives 15 equations. On the contrary, I have only 14 variables. So, FindRoot complains that the numbers do not match.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Even If I add a fictitious variable `k` in `FindRoot` with arbitrary initial value, it finds a singular Jacobian at the initial condition points. See here http://i63.tinypic.com/2is6omd.png . I do not why.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91247/4999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest solution, inferred from a comment by the OP below:

```
obj = Uncompress@Import["/tmp/vector.wdx", "String"];

obj /. {x3 -> 0, x4 -> 0, x5 -> 0, x6 -> 0, x7 -> 0,
        y3 -> 0, y4 -> 0, y5 -> 0, y6 -> 0, y7 -> 0}
(*  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}  *)
```

So `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` may take on any values.

---

*Original numerical approach*

One could minimize the squares of the residuals.  Use higher [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) for a more accurate result.

```
obj = Uncompress@Import["/tmp/vector.wdx", "String"];
vars = Variables@obj;
sumOfSq = Flatten@{obj, #.# - 1 & /@ Partition[vars, 7]} // #.# &;

SeedRandom[0] (* for reproducibility *)

{acc, sol1} = FindMinimum[
  sumOfSq, Thread@{vars, Normalize@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 14]}]
(*
{1.87883*10^-32,
 {x1 -> 0.770225, x2 -> 0.637772, x3 -> -1.07917*10^-10, x4 -> -1.40295*10^-9, 
  x5 -> 1.1682*10^-9, x6 -> 2.92351*10^-8, x7 -> -1.02405*10^-8,
  y1 -> 0.626869, y2 -> -0.779124, y3 -> 1.54472*10^-8, y4 -> -5.33267*10^-12, 
  y5 -> -1.04004*10^-9, y6 -> -5.10446*10^-10, y7 -> -2.39731*10^-10}}
*)

{acc, sol2} = FindMinimum[
  sumOfSq, Thread@{vars, Normalize@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 14]}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 32, MaxIterations -> 500]
(*
{7.6898897201977925978778380482460*10^-64,
 {x1 -> -0.90297104074904814666962995570081, 
  x2 -> 0.42970140745473574888183421474225, 
  ..., 
  y1 -> 0.65977018314385699231516512470880, 
  y2 -> 0.75146743471312275002694856178381, 
  ..., 
  y7 -> -2.6423411962015994155963564116132*10^-18}}
*)

Flatten@{obj, #.# - 1 & /@ Partition[vars, 7]} /. sol1 // Abs // Max
Flatten@{obj, #.# - 1 & /@ Partition[vars, 7]} /. sol2 // Abs // Max
(*
1.09623*10^-16
0.*10^-32
*)
```

Note that `sol1` is pretty accurate at machine precision, just as accurate as `sol2` when it is converted to machine precision:

```
Flatten@{obj, (#.# - 1) & /@ Partition[vars, 7]} /. N@sol2 // Abs // Max
(*  1.38778*10^-16  *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you find another solution? For some reasons I didn't explain, I was expecting to find a solution for all values of x1 x2 y1 y2 and the other variables setted to zero. Can you find a solution for, say, X5 y5 != 0?

Comment: Do you think this method can be generalized by forcing these additional constraints?

Comment: @apt45 Every time I run the code with a new random starting vector, I get a different solution with the higher index variables (e.g. `x5` etc.) close to zero.  Note `sol1` and `sol2` are different, and for `sol2` the higher index variables are much smaller than `sol1`.  It seems the numerics limits the accuracy of these zero value to one-half of working precision, i.e. $10^{-wp/2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, are you saying that you expect the only solution to be for higher index variables very close to zero?

Comment: @apt45 Yes, if they are computed with floating-point. Even a one-bit rounding error would give a relative error of $dx/x\approx2 \times10^{-16}$. In practice, one should expect more than that, because as errors propagate through a computation, relative error is more likely to increase than decrease. The error in the function value should be around $\|df\|.dx$ at most where $\|df\|$ is the (matrix) norm of the derivative, so one should not expect the zeros to be produce zero exactly. There is a somewhat technical, related discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139311/4999).